# Подскажите, в чём ошибка?

Tags: python, алгоритм

Рассматривается множество целых чисел, принадлежащих числовому отрезку [1000; 9999], запись которых в пятеричной системе имеет не менее 6 цифр и заканчивается на 21 или 23. Найдите количество таких чисел и минимальное из них.
Правильный ответ: 550 3136. Подскажите, в чём ошибка? Нужно делать только с помощью циклов, функции нельзя. Попробовал сделать, получилось вот что:

```
s = 0
c = 0
for i in range(1000, 10000):
    n = i
    if i % 5 == 1 or i % 5 == 3:
        if (i // 5) % 5 == 2:
            while i != 0:
                i = i // 5
                s += 1
            if s >= 6:
                c += 1
                if c == 1:
                    n1 = n
print(c, n1)

719 1013
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы не обнуляете значение переменной `s`

```
s = 0
c = 0
for i in range(1000, 10000):
    n = i
    if i % 5 == 1 or i % 5 == 3:
        if (i // 5) % 5 == 2:
            s = 0
            while i != 0:
                i = i // 5
                s += 1
            if s >= 6:
                c += 1
                if c == 1:
                    n1 = n

print(c, n1)
```

также можно немного уменьшить код:

```
c = 0
for i in range(5**5, 10000):
    if i % 25 == 11 or i % 25 == 13:
        c += 1
        if c == 1:
            n1 = i
print(c, n1)
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное

Answer (score 2):

Для решения данной задачи и циклы то не нужны...

```
limit = 9999
min6digits = 1*5*5*5*5*5        #int("100000", 5)
min21 = min6digits + 2*5 + 1    #int("100021", 5)
min23 = min6digits + 2*5 + 3    #int("100023", 5)
count21 = (limit-min21) // (5*5) + 1
count23 = (limit-min23) // (5*5) + 1
print(count21+count23, min21)
```